# Installing Jekyll SEO Tag causes Liquid Exception: Can't convert Hash into String

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I am trying to install [Jekyll SEO Tag](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag/blob/master/docs/installation.md).

When I add `{% seo %}` to my `<head>` section, I am getting the following error:

> Liquid Exception: Can't convert Hash into String. in /_layouts/default.html

The head.html file is located in the _includes folder and it is included in the default.html file as `{% include head.html %}`

What can cause this error?